# Does MongoDB provide document level access to users?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have some collections and I want users to have privileged access to documents (rows) based on a "tag" field. So user1 can see only the documents which have tag = user1 when they query the collection.

Comment: You can set collection-level access to database users (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/). However, what you want doesn't exist out of the box, you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: As stated. Not by user control "out of the box", but really what you are talking about is exactly what you can do with [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) and even at depth in the document. Personally I would advise that your ACL is actually "roles" and not "username" based. Also note that the `$redact` examples are trivial, and for directly the same you are better off implementing in code.

Comment: @joao Could you point towards any resource or link which gives a head start to implementing this

Comment: @NeilLunn: `$redact` does looks like it makes sense in this case. Perhaps you could expand your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I finally wrote an intermediary script in PyMongo to query the database based on the user's attributes (which are saved in separate database). The result of this query is hosted on a separate localhost (or any other IP) port, which is then used by our BI application. The read-write access to the separate database is only provided to the admin who can modify the access that users are privileged to enjoy. The hosting and querying is done using Flask and PyMongo, which can be installed by following following links:

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/installation/